# Set Required=True based on a condition in marshmallow

Tags: python-3.x, dto, marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy, marshmallow-dataclass

I was wondering whether there is a way in marshmallow to have a field to be required depending on another value.

Eg:

{ 'name':'Tom' }

{ 'name':'Arthur', 'job':'teacher' }

I'd like to know if there is a way to make the field job required if isWorking=True (isWorking is not a field in the schema)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [schema validator](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html?highlight=validates_schema#schema-level-validation) with [marshmallow.decorators.validates_schema](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.decorators.html#marshmallow.decorators.validates_schema).

If you set `pass_original=True`, you'll get input data in which you'll find `isWorking`. Then you can raise a `ValidationError` if `job` is missing.